# Counting the number of same ordered pairs in three different permutations

Tags: algorithm, counting

I have three different permutations of the set {1,2,..n}, and I would like to write some code to count the number of pairs of numbers that come in the same order in all three permutations.

As an example with permutation of.
{1,2,3}
(1,2,3).
(3,2,1)

there are 0 such pairs where they come in the same order because `(1,2,3)` and `(3,2,1)` are sorted in both increasing and decreasing order

I want an optimal `O(N*logN)` solution. A hint was given, in which you have to count the number of inversions of each permutation, i.e

> an inversion is the  of pair `(i,j)` such that `i > j` but `a[j] > a[i]`

I can do this in `O(NlogN)`.

So definitely if one pair came in the increasing order in each of the permutations it would add 1 to each inversion count for each permutation. But that isn't true if `i > j` and 
`a[j] > a[i]` (all came in decreasing order) as I should be increasing the count but this doesn't contribute anything to the inversion count. Also afterwards if I can count the number of inversions in each array, but I don't see a link between that and the number of same-ordered pairs.

Comment: Adding an example (with expected output) would make this question much clearer.

Answer (score 1):

For each permutation you have, you should count the number of cases where `a[i] < a[j]`, for each pair of indices `i` and `j` such that `i < j`. Let's call this *non-inversions*. Then, you can find out the result by taking the minimum of the *non-inversion* counts you found.

For instance, in your sample case, the values corresponding for the permutations `(1,2,3)`, `(1,2,3)` and `(3,2,1)` are 3, 3, and 0, respectively.

For a different sample case, you can examine `(1,2,3,4)`, `(1,2,4,3)`, `(1,3,2,4)` and `(4,1,3,2)`. The corresponding counts for these permutations are 6, 4, 5, and 2. The result is `min(6,4,5,2)` because the only tuples that remain ordered in each case are `(1, 2)` and `(1, 3)`.

The key idea behind this solution is based on what *non-inversion* count implies. In an ordered array of size `N`, there are `N(N-1)/2` ordered pairs contributing to the *non-inversion* count. As you introduce some inversions into that array, the relative order of some elements are lost, while some remain. By finding the minimum of the *non-inversion* counts, you can find the number of pairs that preserve their relative ordering in the 'worst' case. (even though this alone is not enough not identify them individually)

If you insist on counting the inversions (i.e. as opposed to the *non-inversions*) the procedure is pretty much the same. Count the inversions for each permutation given to you. Then simply subtract the maximum value you find from `N(N-1)/2`, and obtain the result.

Comment: This is wrong because the triplet `(3,2,1), (3,2,1), (3,2,1)` should have 3 as the answer but your method says 0.

Comment: The author of the question clearly states that, in that case, the answer is 0. ("there are 0 such pairs...") @btilly

Comment: The question is for the number of pairs of numbers appearing in the same order all 3 times.  In the example that I gave, all pairs of numbers appear in the same order all 3 times.  (With larger one first.)  The example that you are looking at included `(3,2,1), (1,2,3)` where no pair is in the same order so the answer is 0.

Comment: Oh, I get it. I'll amend my answer asap.

Comment: For another example, consider `(1,2,3), (2,1,3), (1,3,2)`.  The number of non-inversions is 3, 2, 2.  But the only pair in the same order all 3 times is `(1,3)`.